# Configuration OpenVPN Client

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, vpn, openvpn

I would like to know if any of you would be so kind as to check whether my ovpn configuration file (for OpenVPN Connect) is correctly configured as I find that it works but in a random manner (it could be my connection)?

I used the Windows file and adapted it for macOS.

The configuration file is used on three operating systems, Windows 10 with OpenVPN Gui, MacOS with OpenVPN Connect and I would also like to use it with Ubuntu with OpenVPN Gui.

On Windows 10 and MacOS it works, I used the configuration file for Windows 10, which I adapted for MacOS and it works, but on Ubuntu it doesn't work.
I tried the version used on Windows 10 but also the one used on MacOS. It still doesn't work.

Follow this tutorial https://celo.net/members/index.php/knowledgebase/46/Setup-OpenVPN-in-Gnome-Network-Manager.html. I can't set up the connection between the ubuntu 22.04 client and the synology vpn server.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Dead link is dead.  If the OVPN file works on other OpenVPN clients then it should work for OpenVPN when called on the command line.  Unfortunately, though, it is not going to help for us to look at the *config* file, we need to see the logs from the system about what happens when you are attempting to connect.

Comment: You might be able to get some help on this from https://forums.spacerex.co/c/synology/6

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just copy and past the same `.ovpn` file to other operating systems.  Windows connects to a server differently than Linux.  Consult the [reference manual](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-6/).  For Windows, you need to use double back slashes to files `\\`, only the names `tun` and `tap` are supported for `dev`.